# Javascript: Using `.includes` to find if an array of objects contains a specific object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am a bit new to javascript ES6, and I am having difficulty understanding why the below is not functioning as expected:

```
let check = [{name: 'trent'},{name: 'jason'}].includes({name: 'trent'}); 
// expect true - returns false
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.includes`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) uses the [SameValueZero](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm to determine equality between values. Closely related: [How does the Array.prototype.includes function compare objects](/q/61203925/4642212).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`includes` essentially checks if any element `===` the element you're searching for. In case of objects, `===` means literally the same object, as in the same reference (same place in memory), not the same shape.

```js
var a1 = { name: 'a' }
var a2 = { name: 'a' }

console.log(a1 === a2) // false because they are not the same object in memory even if they have the same data
```

But if you search for an object that is actually in the array it works:

```js
var a1 = { name: 'a' }
var a2 = { name: 'a' }
var array = [a1, a2]

console.log(array.includes(a1)) // true because the object pointed to by a1 is included in this array
```

Answer (score 21):

**Piping**

```
let check = [{name: 'trent'}, {name: 'jason'}]
  .map(item => item.name)
  .includes('trent');
```

**Simple & fast**

```
let check = [{name: 'trent'}, {name: 'jason'}].some(el => el.name === 'trent')
```

Comment: This was cool, I was thinking you should be able to use map/includes for these scenarios but I wasn't sure of the exact way to do it, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't work because objects are never the same, each object has its own reference:

Use `array.prototype.some` instead:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'trent'},{name: 'jason'}];
const obj = {name: 'trent'}; 
const check = arr.some(e => e.name === obj.name);
console.log(check);
```

Answer (score 2):

`includes` check if the **value is present in the array**, and your case the value is a **reference value** and is **different for each declaration of a literal (even if the literal is same)**

**Demo**

```
var a = {name: 'trent'};
var b = {name: 'jason'};
[a,b].includes(a);  //true
```

Use `some` instead to match the entire object:

```
var objToFind = JSON.stringify( {name: 'trent'} );
let check = [{name: 'trent'},{name: 'jason'}].map( s => JSON.stringify( s ) ).some( s => s == objToFind );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate. But in the way you are comparing two objects they are not equal. They should have the same reference in the memory to be equal to each other.

What you can use is something like below

```js
var arr = [{name : "name1"}, {name : "name2"}];

var objtoFind = {name : "name1"}
var found = arr.find(function(element) {
  return element.name === objtoFind.name  ;
});
console.log((found ? true : false));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Check if array contains an `x,y` pair:

Here's an implementation of [Faly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49187976/8112776) that I've used several times.

If you have, for example, an array of XY coordinate pairs like:

```
var px=[{x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:3},{x:3,y:4}];
```

...and you need to check if the array `px` contains a specific XY pair, use this function:

```
function includesXY(arr,x,y){return arr.some(e=>((e.x===x)&&(e.y===y)));}
```

...so with the `px` dataset above:

```
console.log( includesXY( px, 2, 3) ); //returns TRUE
console.log( includesXY( px, 3, 3) ); //returns FALSE
```

```js
var px=[{x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:3},{x:3,y:4}];

console.log( includesXY( px, 2, 3) ); //returns TRUE
console.log( includesXY( px, 3, 3) ); //returns FALSE

function includesXY(a,x,y){return a.some(e=>((e.x===x)&&(e.y===y)));}
```

Comment: *(but I forget how to make it usable instead as* `px.includesXY(x,y)`... *anyone?!)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array.find() method to check if the array includes the object as "Array.includes checks for '===' in the array" which doesn't work for objects

**Example solution:**

```
let check = [{name: 'trent'},{name: 'jason'}].find(element => element.name === 'trent');
```

Comment: When comparing objects, the references are checked instead of the content -> `===` "works" well with objects too.