# Examine duplicate elements in two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays, I want these two to be combined and duplicate items are not lit and only new items are added and I see the combined array in the console
I also want to see the duplicate item in the list on the console
I mean, I need two outputs, one to tell me what a duplicate is, and one to show me a new array of combinations of two arrays without duplicates.
I wrote this code but it does not work properly
Thanks for guiding me

Expected output:

```
newContact : [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oliver"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Liam"
  }
   {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "James"
  }
   {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Lucas"
  }
]
duplicateContacts: Oliver
```

```js
let array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 2, name: "Liam" },
];
let array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 3, name: "James" },
  { id: 4, name: "Lucas" },
];
let newContact = array1.filter((item) => item.id !== array2.id);
console.log("newContact :", newContact);
console.log("duplicateContacts:");
```

Comment: `array2` does not have a property of `id`? Did you mean to compare against an item in the equivalent index in `array2`?

Comment: please add the wanted result. what should happen  if `array1` has another object, not matching in `array2`?

Comment: How to judge it is a duplicate? Just id?

Comment: @mouxiaochou yes id

Comment: @NinaScholz I put the expected output, please check

Answer (score 4):

Guess duplicate meaning the same id, add array entries to a map to find duplicates, and the map contains unique items

```js
const array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 2, name: "Liam" },
];
const array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 3, name: "James" },
  { id: 4, name: "Lucas" },
];

const duplicates = [];
const map = new Map();

const fill = (array) => array.forEach(item => {
  if (map.has(item.id)) {
    duplicates.push(item);
  } else {
    map.set(item.id, item);
  }
});

fill(array1);
fill(array2);

console.log(duplicates);
console.log([...map.values()]);
```

**Edit**

To take arrays as input, create a function

```js
const inspect = (...arrays) => {
    const duplicates = [];
    const map = new Map();

    const fill = (array) => array.forEach(item => {
      if (map.has(item.id)) {
        duplicates.push(item);
      } else {
        map.set(item.id, item);
      }
    });

    arrays.forEach(array => fill(array));

    console.log(duplicates);
    console.log([...map.values()]);
};


const array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 2, name: "Liam" },
];
const array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 3, name: "James" },
  { id: 4, name: "Lucas" },
];

inspect(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Your code does what I expect, but can the `fill` function not be called twice and no need to be called? And give it the input ourselves

Comment: @Good see edit in the answer, you can create a function to accept your arrays as input

Answer (score 3):

with three methods :

- `filter` to get an array of duplicate element
- `map` to recover only an array of one column
- `some` to describe how object in array should be compared

  ```
   const duplicates = array1.filter(value => array2.some(oneElement => oneElement.id === value.id));
  const duplicatesId = array1.filter(value => array2.some(oneElement => oneElement.id === value.id)).map(oneElement => oneElement.id);


  const mergedArray = [ 
   ...array1, 
   ...array2.filter(value => !duplicatesId.some(oneDuplicate => oneDuplicate === value.id))
  ];
  ```

```js
const array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 2, name: "Liam" },
];

const array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Oliver" },
  { id: 3, name: "James" },
  { id: 4, name: "Lucas" },
];

const duplicates = array1.filter(value => array2.some(oneElement => oneElement.id === value.id));
const duplicatesId = array1.filter(value => array2.some(oneElement => oneElement.id === value.id)).map(oneElement => oneElement.id);


const mergedArray = [ 
  ...array1, 
  ...array2.filter(value => !duplicatesId.some(oneDuplicate => oneDuplicate === value.id))
];

console.log(duplicates);
console.log(duplicatesId);
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: The duplicate item does not tell me which one it is

Comment: i edit my reply you can have them with another variable

Comment: I tested your code, it gives me an empty array, please check, thank you

Comment: i edit my reply to have correct answer

Comment: we can't use array1.includes(valueFromArray2) because includes check if object are equal in memory and not have same shape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187940/javascript-using-includes-to-find-if-an-array-of-objects-contains-a-specific

Comment: True, this shows a duplicate, but we do not have a new array that is composed of arrays 1 and 2. Please see my expected output.

Comment: i edit my reply to have a merged array

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from `array2`with all `id` and filter the other array.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ id: 1, name: "Oliver" }, { id: 2, name: "Liam" }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, name: "Oliver" }, { id: 3, name: "James" }, { id: 4, name: "Lucas" }],
    set2 = new Set(array2.map(({ id }) => id)),
    duplicateContacts = array1.filter(({ id }) => set2.has(id));
    allContacts = [...array1, ...array2].filter(
        (s => ({ id }) => !s.has(id) && s.add(id))
        (new Set)
    ),

console.log("allContacts:", allContacts);
console.log("duplicateContacts:", duplicateContacts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: He wanted the 1,2,3,4 in the first array