# Comparing array of ObjectIds to ObjectId

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple use case that used to work in my code, however now I've had to make changes to accommodate an issue I am now having.  Looking to get some insights into why this has changed and requires extra check if anyone can help.  My scenario is as described.

I have an array `userBadgeIds` which holds the following: `[ new ObjectId("59f347fca0f50c0004b5a3ac") ]`

I used to do the following line: `const exists = userBadgeIds.includes(badge._id)` which worked perfectly and told me if the input `badge._id` was in the array.  Both are mongoose `ObjectId` so comparing equivalent in this way seemed perfect (again, it worked!).

However, for whatever reason I now have to compare them in the following way:

```
      const exists = userBadgeIds.map(String).includes(badge._id.toString())
```

Now it works again.  Is there something I'm missing about how the `.includes` compares equivalence or something I'm missing about comparing `ObjectId` specifically around `ObjectId[]`?

Comment: `includes()` uses strict equivalence, so in the case of objects they need to reference the same object to be considered equal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Using \`.includes\` to find if an array of objects contains a specific object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187940/javascript-using-includes-to-find-if-an-array-of-objects-contains-a-specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare objects, they have to be *the exact same object* and not an object that has the same properties.

It's possible that something has changed in your code elsewhere or in a library that turns what was basically this:

```
const obj1 = { _id: 'a' };
const obj2 = { _id: 'b' };
const obj3 = { _id: 'c' };
const searchFor = obj1;

[obj1, obj2, obj3].includes(searchFor); // true
```

Into something that is essentially this:

```
const obj1 = { _id: 'a' };
const obj2 = { _id: 'b' };
const obj3 = { _id: 'c' };
const searchFor = { _id: 'a' };

[obj1, obj2, obj3].includes(searchFor); // false
```

`searchFor` might have the same properties and prototype, but it's not the *exact same object* as `obj1`. Perhaps some code is cloning `badge`, making it not equal to the entries in the `userBadgeIds` array.

Your workaround works, because when you compare strings, they don't have to be *the exact same* string, just have the same *value*.

---

As an aside, there's `ObjectId.prototype.equals()` to compare two (identical *or* equivalent) ObjectIds.

```
// You need to pass searchFor as the second parameter to `some`
// so that `this` is correctly set.
[obj1, obj2, obj3].some(searchFor.equals, searchFor);

// Or you can do:
[obj1, obj2, obj3].some(searchFor.equals.bind(searchFor));

// Or:
[obj1, obj2, obj3].some(id => searchFor.equals(id));
```

`Array.prototype.some` returns `true` if any array entry matches the callback function, like `includes` does for values.